# Change the format of a QDate

Tags: python, string, pyqt, format, qdate

I need to change the format of a `QDate`. Here is my code:

```
 yday = (QtCore.QDate.currentDate().addDays(-1))
```

And I got this result...

```
PyQt4.QtCore.QDate(2015, 4, 2)
```

But I need the date in this format:

> 2015/04/03

Comment: You have to distinguish between internal organisation of objects and their (printable) representation.  
QDate is for computation - if you want it shown somewhere: use formatting means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [datetime.strftime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior)

```
yourdate.strftime('%Y, %m, %d')
```

Answer (score 4):

A `QDate` can be converted to a string using its [`toString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdate.html#toString) method:

```
>>> yday  = QtCore.QDate.currentDate().addDays(-1)
>>> yday.toString()
'Thu Apr 2 2015'
>>> yday.toString(QtCore.Qt.ISODate)
'2015-04-02'
>>> yday.toString('yyyy/MM/dd')
'2015/04/02'
```

Note that this output is from Python3. If you're using Python2, by default, the output will be a `QString` - but it can be converted to a python string using `unicode()`.